# Refresh BootStrap gallery in Blazor .net core 8

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

We're using a catch-all route to render articles in a Blazor .NET 8 RC2 solution.

In our `index.razor`, we have a `@page "/{*pageRoute}"` and an `OnLocationChangedAsync` method that loads a dynamic component `<DynamicComponent Type="ArticleView">` with the article.

When an article is loaded on `ArticleView`, we initialize a Bootstrap Gallery by calling `await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeBootstrapCarousel", "carousel");` in the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method with `firstRender = true`.

Our issue is that when the user clicks a link to a new article, the gallery doesn't refresh and will contain the images from the previous article. The article itself is loaded correctly.

I know I could use a local variable in `ArticleView` and have an `OnLocationChangedAsync`, but I would like another way to dispose of the previous gallery and load the new.

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
   if (firstRender)
   {
      if (DocumentView is not null)
      {
         await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeBootstrapCarousel", "carousel");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried the solution provided? Do you still have any concern on this? Let me know if you need further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

> I know I could use a local variable in ArticleView and have an
> OnLocationChangedAsync, but I would like another way to dispose of the
> previous gallery and load the new.

Actually, the issue you are having with,  this might be because, when you load a new article, the carousel doesn't refresh, and it retains the images from the previous article. Within your onlick even the state has been changed but blazor doesn't know it,  as a result previous images persisted it's state and newer one doesn't get loaded.

In order to resolve your issue, you can do two thing, either use update state change method or manually clear the carousel content. But still it would be better if you could share more details about initializeBootstrapCarousel method, so that it can be investigated accordingly.

Apart from that, you can try following steps:

1. Use state change method:

You can use [StateHasChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.statehaschanged?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method to refresh and imply latest change within your blazor component state. You can do as following:

```
   protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
       if (firstRender)
       {
          if (DocumentView is not null)
          {
             await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeBootstrapCarousel", "carousel");
             StateHasChanged();
          }
       }
    }
```

**Note:** It should reflect your latest state update you can use `InvokeAsync`. If still doesn't work, you can try below manual process.

2. Manually clear carousel content:

If you would like to try manual process in that case, first you have to call your `InvokeVoidAsync` then you should clear or empty your carousel content by following way:

```
function clearUpCarouselContent(carouselId) {
    const carousel = document.getElementById(carouselId);
    carousel.innerHTML = ''; 
}
```

**Note:** Call above function after InvokeVoidAsync and finally call your `initializeBootstrapCarousel` method which loads new carousel object.

Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#handle-prerendering) if you want to study more [details about blazor state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#handle-prerendering)